# trigger and wait for item creation in different BLoC

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

My approach below feels way to complicated for a simple thing I am trying to achive:

I have a list of `Task`s that is managed by a `TaskBloc`. The UI lists all tasks and provides an `execute` button per task. For each click on that button I want to create and store an `Action` (basically the timestamp when the task-execution happened) and show a spinner while the action is created. I have an `ActionBloc` that manages the actions (e.g. creation or getting the history per task).

**I am confused how to setup the communication between the BLoCs.**

---

**This is my approach so far.**

The `ActionsState` just holds a list of all stored actions.

```dart
class ActionsState extends Equatable {
  final List<Action> actions;
  // ... copyWith, constructors etc.
}
```

`Action` is a simple PODO class holding an `id` and `timestamp`.

The `ActionsBloc` is capable of creating `Action`s in response to it's `ActionCreationStarted` event (holding a `int taskId`). Since the `Action` creation is performed in an async isolate there are also events `ActionCreationSucceeded` and `ActionCreationFailed` that are added by the isolate once the request finished. Both hold the `Action` that was either created or whose creation failed.

The `TaskState`:

```dart
class TaskState extends Equatable {
  final Map<int, Task> tasks;
  // ... copyWith, constructors, etc.
```

I added a `executeStatus` to the `Task` model to keep track of the status of the create request in the task list (a specific task cannot be executed multiple times in parallel, but only sequentially while different tasks can be executed in parallel):

```dart
enum Status { initial, loading, success, error }

class Task extends Equatable {
  final int id;
  final Status executeStatus;
  // ...
}
```

I added events for the `TaskBloc`:

```dart
class TaskExecutionStarted extends TaskEvent {
  final int taskId;
  // ...
}
class TaskExecutionSucceeded extends TaskEvent {
  final int taskId;
  // ...
}
class TaskExecutionFailed extends TaskEvent {
  final int taskId;
  // ...
}
```

In the `TaskBloc` I implemented the `mapEventToState` for the new events to set the task status depending on the event, e.g. for `TaskExecutionStarted`:

```dart
Stream<TaskState> mapEventToState(TaskEvent event) async* {
  // ...
  if (event is TaskExecutionStarted) {
    final taskId = event.taskId;
    Task task = state.tasks[taskId]!;
    yield state.copyWith(
      tasks: {
        ...state.tasks,
        taskId: task.copyWith(executeStatus: Status.loading),
      },
    );
  }
  // ...
}
```

**So far this enables the UI to show a spinner per Task** but the `ActionBloc` does not yet know that it should record a new `Action` for that task and the `TaskBloc` does not know when to stop showing the spinner.

---

### PROBLEM

Now the part where I am lost is that I need to actually trigger the `ActionBloc` to create an action and **get an `TaskExecutionSucceeded` (or `...Failed`) event afterwards**. I thought about using a listener on the `ActionsBloc`, but it only provides the state and not the events of the `ActionsBloc` (I would need to react to the `ActionCreationSucceeded` event, but listening to events of an other bloc feels like an anti-pattern (?!) and I do not even know how to set it up).

The core of the problem is, that I may listen on the `ActionsBloc` state but I don't know how to distinguish for which actions of the state I would need to trigger a `TaskExecutionSucceeded` event.

Anyway, I gave the `TaskBloc` a reference to `ActionsBloc`:

```dart
class TaskBloc extends Bloc<TaskEvent, TaskState> {
  final ActionsBloc actionsBloc;
  late final StreamSubscription actionsSubscription;
  // ...
  TaskBloc({
    // ...
    required this.actionsBloc,
  }) : super(TaskState.initial()) {
    actionsSubscription = actionsBloc.listen((state) {
      /* ... ??? ... Here I don't know how to distinguish for which actions of the state
           I would somehow need to trigger a `TaskExecutionSucceeded` event. */
    });
  };
  // ...
}
```

For the sake of completeness, triggering creation of the `Action` is simple by adding the corresponding event to the `ActionBloc` as response to the `TaskExecutionStarted`:

```dart
Stream<TaskState> mapEventToState(TaskEvent event) async* {
  // ...
  // ... set executeStatus: Status.loading as shown above ...
  // trigger creating a new action
  actionsBloc.add(ActionCreationStarted(taskId: taskId));
  // ...
```

---

Of course I aim at clear separation of concerns, single source of truth and other potential sources for [accidential complexity regarding app state structure](https://hackernoon.com/avoiding-accidental-complexity-when-structuring-your-app-state-6e6d22ad5e2a) - but **overall this approach (which still has said problem unsolved before working) feels way to complicated just to store a timestamp per action of a task and keep track of the action-creation-request.**

I appreciate that you read so far (!) and I am very happy about hints towards a clean architecture for that use case.

Comment: Trying to understand the reasoning behind this quite complex architecture. Is there a reason for a separate Action BLoC? I mean, from what you’ve described, it seems actions are conceptually related to Tasks?

Comment: @Riwen: Yes, they are related, but describe their own feature set. Tasks are visible to all users of the app while actions are private to a specific user. A user may view the history of all his/her actions regarding a task and statistics etc (which belongs to the `ActionsBloc` but not to the `TaskBloc`). Users can rate and comment on tasks, select their favorites etc which belongs to the `TasksBloc`. Even if related, putting all in one BLoC is way to much stuff in a single BLoC I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I’ll try to look deeper into this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we ended up doing is the following:

Introduce a `lastCreatedState` in `ActionsState` that represents the status of the last created action.

Instead of always listening to the `ActionsBloc` all the time we listen to its state temporarily when task execution is happening and remember the listener per event.

Once we got a change in the `ActionsBloc` `lastCreatedState` state that indicates success or failure of our task we remove the listener and react to it.

Something along the lines of this:

```dart
/// When a task is executed, we trigger an action creation and wait for the
/// [ActionsBloc] to signal success or failure for that task.
/// The mapping maps taskId => subscription.
final Map<int, StreamSubscription> _actionsSubscription = {};

Stream<TaskState> mapEventToState(TaskEvent event) async* {

  // ...

  // trigger creation of an action
  actionsBloc.add(ActionCreationStarted(taskId: taskId));
  // listen to the result
  // remove any previous listeners
  if (_actionsSubscription[taskId] != null) {
    await _actionsSubscription[taskId]!.cancel();
  }
  StreamSubscription<ActionsState>? listener;
  listener = actionsBloc.stream.listen((state) async {
    final status = state.lastCreatedState?.status;
    final doneTaskId = state.lastCreatedState?.action?.taskId;
    if (doneTaskId == taskId &&
        (status == Status.success || status == Status.error)) {
      await listener?.cancel(); // stop listening
      add(TaskExecutionDone(taskId: taskId, status: status!));
    }
  });
  _actionsSubscription[taskId] = listener;
}

@override
Future<void> close() {
  _actionsSubscription.values.forEach((s) {
    s.cancel();
  });
  return super.close();
}
```

It is not perfect: It requires the pollution of the `ActionsState` and it requires the `TaskBloc` to **not** be disposed before all listeners have finished (or at least have other stuff that ensures the state is hydrated and synced on creation) and the polluted sate.

While the internals are a little more complicated it keeps things separated and makes using the blocs a breeze.